# How to remove an inductor after getting signal from it?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, inductor, design

In the circuit that I've designed, I get 3 different signals and I process them via a microcontroller. 2 of them are from different inductors and 1 of them is from kind of a button. So, my question is can I make an open circuit the inductor after getting a signal from it. And, make short circuit again when I get no signal.

Please forgive me for my bad English. And ask anything that not clear. Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: If you short the signal, no. what are your design specs for input and output?

Comment: When a magnetic field occurs, the circuit getting input via Inductors. And I process these outputs in the microprocessor.

Comment: By specs I mean measurable values.

Comment: I get 58 kHz 20 V amplitude sinus wave from L1 inductor. And I convert it "logic 1 "and "logic 0" via bjt. And "logic 1 " value is 3.3 V "logic 0" is 0 V.

Comment: All specs should be in question including impedance cable length etc. Is that why you had 100 ohms? And diodes? Why overdrive the base? 20V into 100ohms or just into 10M probe?

Comment: You cqn invert anything you want if you have all the I/O specs listed for everything physical and electrical with impedances required

Comment: Did you want to search for how to design a signal detector with inverted logic switch at 3.3V?

Comment: No, I want to separate the inductor L1 from the main circuit after getting a signal from it. 
Normally I get "logic 1" when I get no signal from L1, but if I get a signal from L1 I get "logic 0" for a microcontroller. So, I ask that "Can I make open circuit the inductor L1 after getting 1 sample from it ?"
I don't want a current flowing from L1 to the main circuit.

Comment: Then where does the flyback voltage go?

Comment: Nowhere. I want the voltage to stay on the L1. I forgot to say L1 is not just an inductor. Actually it is a LC circuit. There is a parallel capacitor to L1. I need voltage to stay on this LC because acousto magnetic door can be effected that way. This LC circuit is special for that door. So, if that LC circuit's current flow to the main circuit, I can't effect the door.

Comment: OK but all this info belongs in the question. it seems only only need a peak detector with highimpedance and two stage inverters or non inverting transistor detector.. Ok don’t leave out so much info in your question . What are the cables types and distances?

Comment: I've made the circuit on a stripboard with jumper cables. Maksimum jumper length I've used 8cm.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn to use [Google Translator](https://translate.google.ca/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en) and write a more competent questions with all the measurable details and tolerances. (specifications)
2. I have taken the liberty to make assumptions on your shading pole magnetic door latch and conversion to a low current positive logic level detector to 3.3V
3. The current is shown with an arbitrary source current (50R) at 20Vpp which is amplified 60x for 52kHz and then detected with no loss of power to "1" when the signal is detected.

[Simulation on browser](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCBsB0ZgnJAjAVgMwA4Asz0ZQKYC0A7CEtAExIaVbxqJglhpYlohadIRaUAoAE4gMkLCESjx5JJXAhKlOHFgr1cNAIBKIFFgkz6kKBIhI9yuOQi3w0FAIAmIDiZklIGU4pBOCAGYAhgCuADYALgIA7pJyohDwngmKwlAoJlKQGbLytrBIAgDykskY5mB0KbYCAOauXrkN3nLeYGkoyTKQYN4yECjtAMbp7oY5Uvka-DT08PMLiyggRGCwlCgYJJRoYOwog5A7SFgCYVC9Pj0t8VPqSva9mwgYJ5CYW0hfMRc38tkmL55H4AnwsQwSQqxUFA5pNdqxMSQ%20KeP7gEE5bqXGSFEbweLlOLyWHmYgtaBoEhMDgoSgsJT4AQAZz0Bh8nTGCgswTCTIIAiwrEsLUo3hQ8GJEoUJAA%20uIZWAZdxkDLlAqqArVTLZVoAG6SNloeRIkBGhR8CBoCnm%20yORH9aQSM2CCJwmQmh0WIhWtBffA9Pa%20zDwbgrCiMN5oNDPJBHSghmzteohp3yJim4H25Fp%20IkgVC67kUVQbbkKWJOVYTXcdDq9SeeOMLDoOQoGVyaBUxbdxaaygy%20AyrSCzheEXeEi08jJcxISvV6NoGVttYqJDwFsbPvtudaEQms0mrBtRNwAQABzdElRGfI5rS4LBaE5FRUzjhsJvMnk-mC4SiWYpPixo1IBUgmoS7QjkSRYtGAORIDO5BtvKio1lWK7QHOir9qgQ4CAAHqyECUO42SKPAXCKBIAAiAD2dFCAAOkyTLRAAlhEQwABYCJgd6cCgvDWOgKggAAYkIBAAI4hAQAB2QwAJ58d4J6ruo-CPJpGwgAAwkE55BEMnFBIp-JAA)

Normally we do not do free design work, and just for fun. Here is mine.  (if you like send me a door latch. 8)

Circuit design.

[image]